# A parameterized elliptical integral (Legendre Elliptical Integral)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, special-functions, improper-integrals

$$
K(a,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-a}}{1+2t\cos(\theta)+t^{2}}dt
$$

For $$ -1<a<1;$$  $$-\pi<\theta<\pi$$

I know this integral to be a known tabulated Legendre elliptic integral, however the very fact that the numerator is parameterized completely throws a curveball.

Using:

$$
 K(a,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-a}}{(1+t^{2}) + 2t\cos(\theta)}dt
$$

letting $2\gamma$ = $\theta$ 
$$
\rightarrow K(a,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-a}}{(1+t^{2}) + 2t \cos(2\gamma)}dt
$$

in which case the trig function can be later manipulated using the double angle identity, turning it into a sine function
$$
\rightarrow K(a,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-a}}{(1+t^{2}) + 2t \cos(2\gamma)}dt
$$
$$
\rightarrow K(a,\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-a}}{(1+t^{2}) + 2t(1-(\sin(\gamma))^{2})}dt
$$

So it does have a sine in the denominator that is sufficient for a Legendre Elliptical integral.  The rest is just solving for $k$ and simplifying the expression.  Which leaves me with the parameter $a$.  I have no idea what to do there.

Any help is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Still don't know how to properly square a trig function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not elliptic integral, this can be expressed in terms of elementary functions:
\begin{align}
K(a,\theta)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{-a}dt}{t^2+2\cos\theta\, t+1}=\frac{1}{2i\sin\theta}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{t^{-a}}{t+e^{-i\theta}}-\frac{t^{-a}}{t+e^{i\theta}}\right)dt=\\
=\frac{1}{2i\sin\theta}\left(\frac{\pi e^{ia\theta}}{\sin\pi a}-\frac{\pi e^{-ia\theta}}{\sin\pi a}\right)=\frac{\pi\sin \theta a}{\sin\theta\sin\pi a}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the insight O.L.  I'm on a roll tonight

Comment: I have gum if you want it?

Comment: How did you split the second integral up?  And futhermore, how did you factor a $(e^{-\theta}-e^{theta})$ (the sine term) out front?

Comment: Since $t^2+2t\cos\theta+1=(t+e^{i\theta})(t+e^{-i\theta})$ and $\frac{1}{(t+\alpha)(t+\beta)}=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}\left(\frac{1}{t+\beta}-\frac{1}{t+\alpha}\right)$, we can write $$ \frac{1}{t^2+2t\cos\theta+1}=\frac{1}{(t+e^{i\theta})(t+e^{-i\theta})}$$ $$=\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}\left(\frac{1}{t+e^{-i\theta}}-\frac{1}{t+e^{i\theta}}\right)$$